# Do browsers use built-in jpeg encoders or a system wide one?

Tags: browser, jpeg, encoder

I've had this question for a while now, but have not been able to find an answer. Any hints or references for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely to incorporate a library into their own code. If ***I*** were writing a browser, I would not count on there being a pre-existing library to do JPEG decoder that would be usable.

Comment: That's my suspicion as well. Do you have a point of reference for this or maybe point me to the right track of finding one?

Comment: My point of reference is that I've written JPEG encoders/decoders.

Comment: I have no doubt that you're right, but I am in need of a tangible proof of this being the case. Guess I'm let with digging through each browser's source.

Comment: Yarp, that's the plan.